# How to use trigger to copy tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to copy the data from the table1 to table2 automatically. For example: when data write in table1, table2 should write the same data row in table1. The column name that needs to copy automatically : id, abc

How to do with the trigger?

Edit: here's what i already tried

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER table2 AFTER UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO table select * from table1 where id = NEW.id;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

and it gave me an error

> MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '// CREATE TRIGGER table2 AFTER UPDATE ON table1 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSE' at line 1

Comment: INSERT INTO table - is this a typo (table is a reserved word) should this be INSERT INTO table2 ?And you should be inserting NEW.values not selecting.

Comment: Do you want an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger or `ATER INSERT`?

Comment: Apart from the reserved word this code syntaxes fine for me. What UI tool are you using?

Comment: Also you should not give your trigger the same name as the table (`table2`).

Comment: Pls do not dekete and then repost the same question! Furthermore, mysql seems you have a problem just before //. Check for any invisible, non-printing characters there.

Comment: What API are you using?  The "mysql" commandline tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger_update
AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table_name(val1,va2,....)
VALUES (NEW.val1, NEW.val2, New....);
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This looks more like SQLServer than mariaDB?